# isometry preserves the coefficient of second fundamental form?

Tags: differential-geometry, isometry

isometry preserves the coefficient of 1st fundamental form.
How about the coefficient of 2nd fundamental form?
Is there any counterexample?
Thanks for your answer in advance.

---

Indeed, if F is isometry map,

the coefficient of the 1st fundamental form, such as E
⇒ $E = <x_u,x_u> = <F^{*}(x_u),F^{*}(x_u)> = \bar{E}$
But the coefficient of the 2nd fundamental form,
⇒ $L = - <x_u,U_u> = <F^{*}(x_u),F^{*}(U_u)> = \bar{L}$

Since asking, I notice that $F^{*}(U_u)$ may not the derivative of normal vector of the isometry image.

When is it equal?

Comment: What are your thoughts about that? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

In general the "coefficients" are not preserved. For example, a cylinder is isometric to a plane, but the second fundamental form contains one non-zero radius of curvature, whereas the plane does not. It is the determinant of the second fundamental form - also known as the Gaussian curvature -- which is preserved. *Think about the "coefficients" of the second fundamental form as entries of a diagonal matrix whose determinant needs to be constant*.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.